# Pandas, create new column applying groupby values

Tags: pandas, group-by, multiple-columns

I have a DF:

```
Col1   Col2    Label
0      0        5345
1      0        7574
2      0        3445
0      1        2126
1      1        4653
2      1        9566
```

So I'm trying to groupby on Col1 and Col2 to get index value based on Label column like this:

```
df_gb = df.groupby(['Col1','Col2'])['Label'].agg(['sum', 'count']) 
df_gb['sum_count'] = df_gb['sum'] / df_gb['count']
sum_count_total = df_gb['sum_count'].sum() 
index = df_gb['sum_count'] / 10 

Col2  Col1       
0     0          2.996036
      1          3.030063
      2          3.038579

1     0          2.925314
      1          2.951295
      2          2.956083

2     0          2.875549
      1          2.899254
      2          2.905063
```

Everything so far is as I expected. But now I would like to assign this 'index' groupby df to my original 'df' based on those two groupby columns. If it was only one column it's working with map() function but not if I would like to assign index values based on two columns order.

```
df_index = df.copy()
df_index['index'] = df.groupby([]).apply(index)
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Tried with agg() and transform() but without success. Any ideas how to proceed?

Thanks in advance.
Hristo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you need [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
a = df.join(index.rename('new'), on=['Col1','Col2'])
print (a)
   Col1  Col2  Label    new
0     0     0   5345  534.5
1     1     0   7574  757.4
2     2     0   3445  344.5
3     0     1   2126  212.6
4     1     1   4653  465.3
5     2     1   9566  956.6
```

Or [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['new']=df.groupby(['Col1','Col2'])['Label'].transform(lambda x: x.sum() / x.count()) / 10
print (df)
   Col1  Col2  Label    new
0     0     0   5345  534.5
1     1     0   7574  757.4
2     2     0   3445  344.5
3     0     1   2126  212.6
4     1     1   4653  465.3
5     2     1   9566  956.6
```

And if no `NaN`s in `Label` column use solution from [Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47436198/pandas-create-new-column-applying-groupby-values/47436284?noredirect=1#comment81828061_47436284) suggestion, thank you:

```
df.groupby(['Col1','Col2'])['Label'].transform('mean') / 10
```

If need count only non `NaN`s values by [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.count.html) use solution with `transform`.

Comment: With join is working perfectly. Will try it with GroupBy.transform() as well. Thanks a milion mate! :)

Comment: Yes, second solution should be faster. You are welcome!

Comment: Second can be `df.groupby(['Col1','Col2'])['Label'].transform('mean') / 10`?

Comment: @Zero - Thanks, added to answer.